# Internet slows down significantly with HDMI-VGA adapter

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have purchased a HDMI to VGA adapter for my monitor a couple of years ago. I have constantly had internet issues where it would drop-off or load very slowly.

I have now realised the cause was actually this adapter. When a video is buffering I can unplug the adapter for my second monitor and it loads instantly. Speed tests also double in speed when the adapter is removed.

I only have a HDMI port and VGA port on my PC and have two VGA monitors.

My question is, is this common in all HDMI-VGA adapters? How can I stop these issues without having to buy a new monitor or graphics card?

**Speeds Test Results:**

Only HDMI/VGA Adapter Monitor: 7Mbps

Only VGA: 22Mbps

Both Monitors: 7Mbps

Only HDMI TV: 21Mbps

Both VGA and HDMI TV (No Adapter): 21Mbps

Comment: This should be totally unrelated. What system are you running on? Could it be that your hardware is just really, really low power and it's having issue rendering two displays? Does it help if you display one of the displays (without disconnecting the adapter)?

Comment: [ebuyer] (http://www.ebuyer.com/735864-zoostorm-origin-desktop-pc-7260-0145) This is my PC. Its an I7 with Intel HD Graphic with Windows 10. Its only got integrated graphics so not expecting a lot. Its does appear to help displaying one display but interestingly it depend on which display. If I display on the HDMI/VGA adapter screen  the internet is significantly slower than the VGA only one.

Comment: What happens if you remove the VGA monitor or reduce the resolution? Seems like power issue. The network card/CPU isnt getting necessary power to keep up with the connection.

Comment: Sorry, I am confused by what you mean. Do you mean remove the VGA only connection or the one with the HDMI/VGA adapter? They are both VGA monitors.

Comment: Looking at the back of the system, I wonder if somehow there's interference, since the HDMI port is nearish the network port.. Those speeds look pretty bad too, even under ideal situations.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using a wireless card so its even more likely to be interference. I was wondering if the adapter perhaps produces interference or maybe the PC is using more power going through the adapter.  We are getting 33Mbps to wired PC's in the house. This PC is quite a long way from the router.

Comment: I am having the very same issue on my Lenovo Laptop. Can't fix it!